# Derivation of Teukolsky equation doesn't match

Tags: general-relativity

I am trying to derive Teukolsky equation on Kerr spacetime using SageMath and

(1) [(Δ+3γ−γ∗+4μ+μ∗)(D+4ϵ−ρ)−(δ∗−τ∗+β∗+3α+4π)(δ−τ+4β)−3ψ2]ψ4=0.

Like he did in his [paper](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1973ApJ...185..635T). But I did not have success, the expression is too big and doesn't match the one on his paper. I read about it and tried to use ψ4 = ψ*p^4, but still did not work. Can someone help me, please?

I need to obtain the teukolsky equation using (1), have ever someone used (1) to derivation of it and could give some hint? Thanks.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Newman Penrose formalism?

Comment: I am. I know the spin coefficients and Weyl scalars.